Snowflake - Use streams with merge
if i have a stream that do CDC over a table and then use the data captured on the stream doing a merge into a final table.. What happen if the merge fails for any reason, the stream is emptied anyways or if the merge doesn't finish the data still remains in the stream?
Thanks

The data will remain in the stream. DML statements have an implicit transaction round them and if they fail then they are rolled back and the stream offset is not updated.
This is covered in the documentation here

another question man, if i have a table, and i do a left join to a stream, if none of the rows join each other, and the data of the table 1 is merge to a final table, the stream is still emptied?

My understanding is that if you run a DML statement (Insert/update/delete) and the source is a stream then the stream window will move if that statement commits - regardless of what the statement actual does (or doesn't) do
